# how can you make a processing jquery button, like the follow button on twitter?

Tags: php, jquery, css

for example the twitter follow button when pressed it sends an ajax call through php script and then displays unfollow:

how could that be acheived using jquery and css?

Comment: Why don't you hire a programmer? This is at least the 3rd question today about a simple script.

Comment: Of course you are allowed Solomon, but instead of asking for scripts, you should at-least try it first and then ask us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$("#folow").click(function (){
     $.ajax(
     {
        type: "POST",
        url: "someAction.php",
        success: function(result) {
            $("#folow").val('unfolow');
            // do some more stuff
        }
     });
});
```

This will make the ajax call to an php action, and change the buttons text to something else when the ayax call is succesfull.
In the php action you do the 'logic you need'.

for more info over tha ajaxcall see: 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

I think you want jQuery UI, especially the button plugin: http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/

You can easily use it:

```
$('#my-button').button();
```